# Something similar OSGI in Microsoft?

Tags: .net, osgi

I am a .Net developer but I need to learn OSGI, is there any similar concept to OSGI in .Net to learn it by example and faster ? Thanks

Comment: Probably not. To some extent you've got [application domains](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2bh4z9hs.aspx) for isolating components, and some of the IoC frameworks e.g. [Castle](http://docs.castleproject.org/Windsor.MainPage.ashx) have vaguely similar concepts of lifecycle, and to a lesser extent wiring up components, but I can't think of anything quite the same. Why not just experiment in Java? Java is fairly easy to understand if you're a C# developer, the IDEs aren't too unfriendly and the package managers are decent too.

Answer (score 0):

I found this project [(OSGI.NET)](http://osgi.codeplex.com/) in codeplex and it looks good reference for me. I hope it helps others that are looking for the same answer.